# How do I tell if I'm (not) gaining skill XP?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to disprove [a claim that Sneak XP can be earned by sneaking around a corpse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/181630/46216). However, I may run (or crawl) into complication in measurement. Is the only way to check if I'm gaining (Sneak) skill XP by whether or not it levels up or by visually comparing the Sneak XP bar in the Skills/Stats menu?

Update: I completed [the video](http://youtu.be/9U1QyJbhKzo) anyway.

Comment: Are you on the PC? iirc you can use console commands to get the real values.

Comment: Ah yes, I am playing on PC. player.getav Sneak?

Comment: Um, unfortunately, it seems to only give the level of the Skill and not how much XP it has. Same with getAvInfo.

Comment: damn, that sucks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way you can tell if you gained any xp is first to find out how much skill usage (i.e. xp) it takes you to get to the next level of sneak.

You can do this via trial and error using the command (save first):

> player.advskill sneak (number)

Once you figure out the exact number (lets say its X), you can then reload your save and proceed with your experiment.  If you have gained experience, then the command:

> player.advskill sneak (X-1)

should bump you to the next level.  If not, then you haven't gained any xp.

Comment: Unfortunately, a down-side to this is that the "player.advskill" console command works with floating points and I've gone down to trillionths. Not necessarily impossible, but (more) tedious (than I imagined).

Comment: @NiteCyper you dont' have to worry about floating points I believe most of the skills in game advance by integers.